# How do I calculate an expected value?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I read the introduction, the problem, couldn't solve it, viewed the explanation, but still don't understand it. You calculate an expected value by adding up weighed averages, don't you (at least, Brilliant's introduction contained exactly that)? Why is there this (9/10)^7? Please walk me through this solution. The question of the problem is "After all seven times, what is the expected number of fish that remain unmarked?"

[image]

[image]

Comment: $\frac 9 {10}$ is the probability a particular fish is not caught in a particular attempt, and $\left(\frac 9 {10}\right)^7$ is the probability a particular fish is not caught in any of the seven attempts (assuming equal probabilities of being caught and independence of attempts)

Comment: Expected value for a discrete variable (like this one) is usually *defined* as a weighted sum of values, but there are theorems about expected value that allow you to *calculate* it in different ways. This exercise uses one such theorem, linearity of expectation. You need to know and understand that fact in order to understand the solution to the problem. You can also try to solve the problem directly by working out the probabilities of all outcomes and taking a weighted sum, but then it will take you a much, much longer time to solve with lots of tedious calculation.

Comment: If you want a better answer, try asking the question more specifically. What did you find confusing about the explanation? Which parts did you understand, where did you get lost? Do you need someone to explain what an indicator variable is and how it is used here? What do you know about linearity of expectation?

Comment: You haven't reacted to my solution to your previous question. Please do it. It's a matter of politeness.

Comment: @jeanmarie I upvoted your answer. I'm not sure what else you expected. You were second to resolve the issue so you didn't get the accepted answer check mark, the other user did

Answer (score 1):

$F_i$ is a Bernoulli random variable, i.e. it takes value $1$ if the $i$th fish is unmarked at the end of her experiment and $0$ otherwise.  Since in each round, there is a $9/10$ chance a given fish $i$ is not marked, by independence, there is a $(9/10)^7$ chance that particular fish is not marked in all 7 rounds (i.e. when $F_i=1$). Thus the expected value of $F_i$ is $$E[F_i]=1\times (9/10)^7+0\times (1-(9/10)^7)=(9/10)^7.$$

Now we use the fact that the number of fish unmarked after 7 rounds is just $F_1+...+F_{10}$ and linearity of expectation.

Comment: Why did you multiply those 9/10 probabilities by themselves seven times? What formula did you use?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev I used the fact that if $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ (with seven events instead of two). In this case, the events are: a given fish is not marked after round 1, the fish is not marked after round 2, the fish is not marked after round 3, etc.